# How to change the input for the handle to a different html file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Sorry if I'm unable to explain well, but I've been developing a code for a real-time chat application using javascript, HTML, CSS and also WebSockets. I've created a new login page to enter a username, as this option was previously on the chat window itself on another page. But I don't know how to move the handle id so that it still saves for the chat, I'll leave the code below.

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Isolation Talk</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.dev.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="isolation-talk">
            <form class="box" action="index.html" method="post">
              <h1>Login</h1>
              <input id="handle" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
              <input class="Login" onclick="window.location.href='chat.html'" type="button" value="Login" />
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
    <script src="/chat.js"></script>
</html>
```

chat.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Isolation Talk</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.dev.js"></script>
        <link href="/chat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="isolation-talk">
            <div id="chat-window">
                <div id="output"></div>
                <div id="feedback"></div>
            </div>
            <input id="message" type="text" placeholder="Message" />
            <input id="handle" type="text" placeholder="Username" />
            <button id="send">Send</button>
        </div>

    </body>
    <script src="/chat.js"></script>
</html>
```

chat.js:

```
// Make connection
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4000');

// Query DOM
var message = document.getElementById('message'),
      handle = document.getElementById('handle'),
      btn = document.getElementById('send'),
      output = document.getElementById('output'),
      feedback = document.getElementById('feedback');

// Emit events
btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    socket.emit('chat', {
        message: message.value,
        handle: handle.value
    });
    message.value = "";
});

message.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
    socket.emit('typing', handle.value);
})

// Listen for events
socket.on('chat', function(data){
    feedback.innerHTML = '';
    output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.handle + ': </strong>' + data.message + '</p>';
});

socket.on('typing', function(data){
// Is typing feature //    feedback.innerHTML = '<p><em>' + data + ' is typing a message...</em></p>';
});
```

Comment: What is yout problem? What is the handle id that you want move?

Comment: The handle input: <input id="handle" type="text" placeholder="Username" /> that is in chat.html needes to work where its located in index.html

Comment: Do you want move dinamicaly the your `<input id = "handle" type = "text" placeholder = "Username" />`?

Comment: I just want it to function in the index.html as it would in the chat.html